# Setting parameter range with caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using the adaptive method to find my best model parameters. However I could not find a way to set the parameter min and max values.

For instance in the following simplify example I would like to force train function to find a k between 8 and 12. Of course I know that, for this simple case, I could use the tuneGrid parameter.

```
library(caret)
ctrl2 <- trainControl(method = "adaptive_cv",
                      repeats = 5)

mod2 <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris,
              method = "knn",
              tuneLength = 3,
              trControl = ctrl2)
```

Comment: I do not think this is possible with `caret`, it is possible with `mlr` however I do not think `adaptive_cv` is an option with `mlr`. One workaround is to generate a random uniform sample between min and max for each hyper parameter and provide that as a grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tuneGrid` to specify which tuning values to chose in the training. Please note that different models (i.e. knn, svm,..) will have different tuning values.

Also, as it states in `?caret::train` :

> tuneGrid
>   A data frame with possible tuning values. The columns are named the same as the tuning parameters. Use getModelInfo to get a list of tuning parameters for each model or see http://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html. (NOTE: If given, this argument must be named.)

The working code in your case would be:

```
library(caret)

ctrl2 <- trainControl(method = "adaptive_cv",
                      repeats = 5)

grid_knn <- expand.grid(k=8:12)

set.seed(100)

mod2 <- train(Species ~ ., data = iris,
              method = "knn",
              tuneGrid = grid_knn,
              trControl = ctrl2)
```

Which gives the output:

```
> mod2

 k-Nearest Neighbors 

150 samples
  4 predictor
  3 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Adaptively Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k   Accuracy   Kappa  Resamples
   8  0.9600000  0.940   5       
   9  0.9733333  0.960  50       
  10  0.9733333  0.960  50       
  11  0.9746667  0.962  50       
  12  0.9666667  0.950   6       

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 11.
```